# Facebook Flash Application background color doesn't show up

Tags: flash, background, facebook

How to make the flash background color show up?
I tried swfbgcolor doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this link  :

```
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:swf
```

In the fb:swf try this :

```
<fb:swf 
swfbgcolor="000000" 
imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;" 
swfsrc='http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxxx' 
imgsrc='http://img.youtube.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxx/2.jpg' 
width='340' height='270' />
```

Now set the swfbgcolor with what you want in hex and your done :)

Comment: tried b4 cannot work. what i meant is the original background usedin the flash doesn't show up.

Comment: The original background color or the original background? The original background color will not work. You will need to specify it wherever you are loading the swf file.

Comment: Today suddenly my flash backgrd turns black and I realised swfbgcolor can work alr! It was facebook problem...
Btw, how come the original backgrd color cannot work? Facebook disallows that for what reason?

Comment: I also realised if an object is too big (for eg a rect with a only 1 color), it doesn't show up in Facebook. What if I want a gradient bckgrd instead of just 1 color, I can't do that in Facebook?

Comment: It removes it. The simplest thing is to make a movieclip and paste it in the background.